# How do I change X resolution on Linux mint 13?

Tags: linux-mint, resolution

I have an old Sony Vaio system with linux mint 13 (Mate desktop).

For the life of me I can't recall how to change the screen resolution. The widescreen monitor is set to 1920x1080 but it won't do whatever the grub default is nor do the console windows come up due to "out of range" X resolution.

How do I change this? I could have sworn there was a menu item for it, but I might be thinking of nvidia systems.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Display.  In the Resolution combobox you can choose the resolution for your monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno much about Linux Mint, but I found [this](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/37) after a quick Google search. Give it a go.